# SingleChildScrollView cannot be shown

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview

SingleChildScrollView cannot be shown on the Homepage.dart which use to display the card from Homepagecard.dart, but no error is stated. Is any problem happening with my code?

SingleChildScrollView cannot be shown on the Homepage.dart which use to display the card from Homepagecard.dart, but no error is stated. Is any problem happening with my code?

SingleChildScrollView cannot be shown on the Homepage.dart which use to display the card from Homepagecard.dart, but no error is stated. Is any problem happening with my code?

homepage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:two_life/model/product.dart';
import 'package:two_life/screens/homepagecard.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 350,
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 147, 145, 145),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Text(
                      "Welcome to 2.LIFE!\n\n Enjoy your shopping with us via 2.LIFE!!",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Text('Recommended',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ),
            ),
// Here is the problem 
            SingleChildScrollView(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  ...List.generate(
                    productList.length - 5,
                    (index) => Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 0.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        child: PlaceCard(
                            product: productList[index], press: () {}),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

homepagecard.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:two_life/screens/productDetails.dart';
import '../model/product.dart';

class PlaceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlaceCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.product,
    this.isFullCard = false,
    required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Product product;
  final bool isFullCard;
  final GestureTapCallback press;
// i want to display the card
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      height: 200,
      child: Column(children: [
        AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: isFullCard ? 1 : 1,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                topRight: Radius.circular(15),
              ),
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(product.pimages), fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 100,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 145, 145, 145),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                offset: const Offset(5, 5),
                blurRadius: 10,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 109, 109, 109).withOpacity(0.56),
              )
            ],
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductDetails(product)));
            },
            child: Column(children: [
              Text(product.pname,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 13,
                    ),
                  ),
            ]),
          ),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what I expected

[image: This is what I expected]

Comment: Maybe try wrapping the `SingleChildScrollView` with `Expanded`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a SingleChildScrollView inside a Stack, remember that the SingleChildScrollView has a variable height or width, so if you want to have both widgets you need to wrap the stack into a container and wrap this container into your SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: still not working